# My menus on website refuse to change colour

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2012

when I try to change my Categories and Departments menu colour they don't apply the colour I selected and remain the same:

```
.DepartmentsList {
    border: #006600 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #006600;
}
.DepartmentsListHead {
border: 1px solid #006600;
background-color: #006600;
background-repeat: repeat;
```

```
<%@ Register src="UserControls/DepartmentsList.ascx" tagname="DepartmentsList" tagprefix="uc1" %>
```

```
<%@ Register src="UserControls/SearchBox.ascx" tagname="SearchBox" tagprefix="uc3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
  <title>Farm Shop: Online Store</title>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="Window">
      <div class="Main">
        <div class="Left">
          <div class="Container">
            &nbsp;<uc3:SearchBox ID="SearchBox1" runat="server" />
              <uc1:DepartmentsList ID="DepartmentsList1" runat="server" />
              <uc2:CategoriesList ID="CategoriesList1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I don't know how to do the whole indent thing sorry, do I have to press Space 4 times before every line of code?

Comment: You really need to post your HTML rather than asp code, so we can see what your browser sees. ATM your CSS doesn't relate to your HTML fragment.

Comment: Where do I find the html code to post here? Thanks

Comment: One option is to view your browser's source code. (`View > Source` or similar.)

Comment: Hi is there a way to email you my HTML code please it won't let me edit it in.. I can't seem to properly format my code with the 4 spaces thing and it says something about localhost can't be posted here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I know nothing as .NET, however, in your style sheet you call classes but within your code you use 'id'.

Try adding the class to the tag or rename the class in the style sheet to reflect the id.

For example:

From

```
.DepartmentsList {
    border: #006600 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #006600;
}
```

To:

```
#DepartmentsList {
    border: #006600 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #006600;
}
```

Or:

```
<uc1:DepartmentsList ID="DepartmentsList1" runat="server" class="DepartmentsList" />
```

Hope this makes sense and helps in some way.

Regards

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work, any other suggestions? :/

Comment: I think we need to see all the code. I notice from an early posting you may have been having a bit of bother. The easiest way would be to block all the code and copy. Then paste the code into stackoverflow. Now block the code you've just pasted and use ctrl+k. This will indent the whole code by four spaces. Does that make sense?